# boost::asio infinite loop

Tags: boost, boost-asio, tcpserver

this is my `boost::asio` server

```
class Server: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Server>, private boost::noncopyable{
  private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket   _socket;
  public:
    explicit Server(boost::asio::io_service& ios, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint):_acceptor(ios, endpoint), _socket(ios){

    }
    void start(){
       accept();
    }
    void accept(){
       std::cout << "accepting " << std::endl;;
      _acceptor.async_accept(_socket, boost::bind(&Server::handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    void handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
       const std::string message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\n\r\nHello, world!";
       if(!ec){
         boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), boost::bind(&Server::write_handler, this));
       }else{
         std::cout << ec << std::endl;
       }
       accept();
    }
    void write_handler(){

    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket(){
      return _socket;
    }
};


int main(){
  boost::asio::io_service ios;
  const unsigned int port = 5050;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);

  Server server(ios, endpoint);
  server.start();

  ios.run();
  return 0;
}
```

for the first time it responds with an 'Hallo World';
Then it just keeps looping in `accept` <--> `handler` loop and doesn't write the welcome message. `ec` prints

```
asio.misc:1
accepting 
asio.misc:1
accepting 
asio.misc:1
accepting 
asio.misc:1
accepting 
asio.misc:1
accepting 
asio.misc:1
accepting 
......
```

and never stops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite loop is the result of `_socket` being in use.  The first `async_accept()` works because `_socket` is not in use.  However, the `_socket` is never closed, so additional calls to `async_accept()` with `_socket` are going to fail.  The `async_accept()`'s *peer* argument expects that the socket is not in use, as it is going to use the socket for a new connection.  This can be resolved by either:

- Allocating a new socket per connection.  Consider managing the sockets via `boost::shared_ptr`.  This allows the server to handle multiple concurrent connections.
- Closing the `_socket` in the `write_handler`, then invoke `accept()`.  This limits the server to one connection at a time.

Also, be careful with `async_write()`.  Ownership of the underlying buffer memory is retained by the caller, who must guarantee that it remains valid until the handler is called.   In this case, `message` will pop off of the stack before `write_handler()` is invoked.  With `message` being `const`, consider making it `static` to guarantee its duration.

Use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` when passing in the object to the instance to the `bind` call.  Otherwise, the instance pointed to by `this` may be deleted, as referencing counting only properly takes place when using `shared_from_this()`.

Finally, when printing `boost::system::error_code`, use the `error_code.message()` method to get a more meaningful message.  In the case of the infinite loop, it would print "Already open".

Here is the modified `handler()` and `write_handler()` code that supports one connection at a time:

```
void accept(){
   std::cout << "accepting " << std::endl;;
  _acceptor.async_accept(_socket, boost::bind(&Server::handler, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
void handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
   // Guarantee message will remain valid throughout the duration of async_write.
   static const std::string message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\n\r\nHello, world!";
   if(!ec){
     // write_handler will accept the next connection once it is done with the socket.
     boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), boost::bind(&Server::write_handler, shared_from_this()));
   }else{
     std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
     // Try accepting on error.
     accept();
   }
}
void write_handler(){
   _socket.close();
   // Now that the socket is closed, new connectiosn can be accepted.
   accept();
}
```

Comment: Okay So I've made a `Session` Class that has a `socket`. and I am creating a new `Session` by `Session::create()` in `Server::accept` and `class Session: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Session>, private boost::noncopyable` is that okay ?

Comment: That sounds okay.  If you are not already, consider allocating the write buffers, such as `message` as a member variable in the `Session` class to guarantee the lifespan.

Comment: Thanks I've done a compilable Implementation with some problem. its on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021735/boost-asio-stateful-server-design

Comment: Saved my butt! I didn't realize the socket had to be closed first. Thank you from the future for the detailed explanation.