# boost asio stateful server design

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am writing a Server application on `boost::asio`

1. Here I instantiate a `Server` that owns an `io_service`
2. Server is started by `server.start()` method which calls `Server::accept()` and that creates a new `Session` **even before it gets a new connection**
3. Calls `_acceptor.async_accept` thats set a callback that calls `Session::handler()` method which does the handshaking.

Now is it okay to create a socket even before getting a new client ?
and in this code the Session is auto destructed after writing an `"Hello "` Message which is Okay in case of HTTP, But I want to carry on a Stateful Communication. so socket must `async_wait` for reading after it just wrote this `"Hallo "`. also I'd like to know whether this design is okay ? or it Has any design flaw.

Here goes My Compilable Code

~

```
class Session: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Session>, private boost::noncopyable{
  private:
    size_t _id;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket   _socket;
  public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Session> pointer;
    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& ios){
      return pointer(new Session(ios));
    }
  private:
  explicit Session(boost::asio::io_service& ios): _socket(ios){
    static size_t counter = 0;
    _id = counter++;
    std::cout << ">> Session " << id() << " constructing" << std::endl;
  }
  public:
    void handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
      const std::string message = (boost::format("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %2%\r\n\r\nHello, %1%!") % id() % (7+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(id()).length())).str();
      if(!ec){
        boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), boost::bind(&Session::write_handler, this));
      }else{
        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
      }
    }
    void write_handler(){

    }
    size_t id() const{
      return _id;
    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket(){
      return _socket;
    }
    virtual ~Session(){
      std::cout << ">> Session " << id() << " destructing" << std::endl;
    }
    };

class Server: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Server>, private boost::noncopyable{
  private:
    boost::asio::io_service        _ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
  public:
    explicit Server(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint):_acceptor(_ios, endpoint){

    }
    void start(){
      accept();
      _ios.run();
    }
    void accept(){
      std::cout << "accepting " << std::endl;;
      Session::pointer session = Session::create(_ios);
      _acceptor.async_accept(session->socket(), boost::bind(&Server::handler, this, session, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    void handler(Session::pointer session, const boost::system::error_code &ec){
      if(!ec){
        session->handler(ec);
      }else{
        //possible destroy session ? but how to destroy a shared pointer ?
      }
      accept();
    }
};


int main(){  
  const unsigned int port = 5050;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);

  Server server(endpoint);
  server.start();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall design looks okay, but there are a few implementation errors:

- `Session::handler()`: `message`, the underlying buffer provided [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), may go out of scope before `async_write()` is invoked.  This is a violation of the guarantee required by the API.  Consider making `message` a member variable for `Session`, or make it `static` within the member function.  This is the relevant excerpt from the documentation:

  > Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.  Here is the relevant excerpt from the documentation:
- For objects inheriting from `boost::enable_shared_from_this`, use `shared_from_this()` instead of the `this` pointer when passing the instance handle to `boost::bind`.  Otherwise, it is possible that the object instance pointed to by `this` may be deleted prior to the handler running.

Also, to address the question in the code comment within the `Server::handler()`, if an error occurs, the `Session` will be deleted once the handler returns since it is managed via a `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks. But This one is stateless. It destroyes the socket after one write. I want to make it stateful. How ?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  As long as the shared pointer is kept alive via a queued handler, then the `Session` and its socket will not be destroyed.  For example, you could introduce an asynchronous read loop with [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html).  Also, keep in mind that `HTTP` is a stateless protocol; it may affect testing your application if using an `HTTP` client.

Comment: Well I'll use things like `telnet` or socket to test. and as you said I replaced `this` with `shared_from_this()` in `boost::bind(&Server::handler, shared_from_this(), session, boost::asio::placeholders::error)` which is giving me runtime error `accepting 
>> Session 0 constructing
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
Aborted`

Comment: My apologies.  For `Server`, you can use `this` instead of `shared_from_this` because it is being allocated and managed as an automatic variable on the stack.  Consider either removing the inheritance to `enable_shared_from_this<Server>` or making the constructor private and introduce a factory function that returns a a `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Well, I've made a call to `async_read` but that's even not putting the server in listening mode. I actually want a two way communication. can you please describe it a little more on how `async_read` can be used here to make the session listening and talking both way ? e.g. to close the session it must be explicitly instructed on the last message of conversation.

Comment: Use the [asio async tcp echo server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) as a reference.  If you have questions about it, feel free to post them.